# No application integration exists for rails. Compass and rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, compass-sass

I started a rails 4 project and added the following gem (supposedly, it has rails 4 support)

```
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.alpha.0'
```

However, after bundle install and $ bundle exec compass init I keep getting

```
No application integration exists for rails.
```

Anyone knows why ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same error with compass-rails v1.1.3 and rails 4, when running "bundle exec compass init rails", but when I run "bundle exec compass init" (omitting "rails") it works fine for me. The version of compass-rails you are using has been yanked since last July (see here: http://rubygems.org/gems/compass-rails/versions/2.0.alpha.0).

Comment: This is the same as running the command for a random-like project. It adds sass and stylesheets directories. There is no configuration for it to work with rails, with this command.

Comment: This is true, but I did not imply that this was a command for Compass to work with Rails. After all, no "special" command is necessary for Compass to work with Rails, as long as you include the required gems.

Comment: Well... I didn't fully understand the process of using Compass with Rails. I don't remember if I actually tried to use it or if I just gave up. So, if I add the gems, I can start importing Compass's files from anywhere in my stylesheets?

Comment: You need to add the required gems to your Gemfile, a config.rb file inside your app's root directory and any Compass .scss or .sass stylesheets inside vendor/assets/stylesheets. I can always provide you with a more detailed answer, if you submit this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `project_type = :rails` from your config file.